# use unserilize for compute lenght array and special value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, count

My data was save in database in serialize format.
I want to unserialize data that i get from select query then compute length of this and return index of some value in data.
result of unserialize data is like

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => 3445 [2] => [3] => 3446 [4] => [5] => 3452 [6] => [7] => 3530 [8] => 3555 )
```

how can I compute array length and return index of special value?
in my code length of value false number

```
$str = $row->cur;
$str_len=unserialize($str);
print_r($str_len);
$str_length=count($str_len);
```

Comment: I think you're just looking for array_search. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `count($arr)` to compute array length of array `$arr`, and `array_search($needle, $arr)` to get the index of a value (`$needle`) you're looking for in the source array (`$arr`).

```
<?php

$arr = ['', 3445, '', 3446, '', 3452, '', 3530, 3555,];

$arrayLen = count($arr);
echo 'array length : ' . $arrayLen; // 9
echo PHP_EOL;

// return index of value
$needle = 3452;
$index = array_search($needle, $arr);
echo 'found value ' . $needle . ' at index : ' . $index; // found value 3452 at index 5
```

**Update:**
If you want to count only non-empty values in your array, you can use `array_filter()`:

```
// Count only non empty array entries
$arrNonEmpty = array_filter($arr, function($element) { return !empty($element); });
$count = count($arrNonEmpty);
```

[`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) invokes a callback function (an anonymous function in this case) to filter and return all non-empty values in the source array.

**Updated:** You can play with the code [here](https://3v4l.org/2fM18)

Comment: thank you, But this code calculate count of array that is empty. how can i show result 5 instead of 9 for count array?

Comment: @mickmackusa thanks, re. the answer, I was actually not satisfied with it, and didn't have time to refactor. keep up the good work!